# How to prepopulate Checkbox in Struts2 jquery grid column ?Note( The checkbox should also be editable)

Tags: struts2-jquery-grid

Am using Struts2 jquery grid to show List objects. I have a boolean attribute in it, which I wish to show as a Checkbox in UI(ie. Checked when 'True' and Unchecked when 'false'). This checkbox should also be editable in UI.Finally on submit I want only the records for which these checkbox values are changed.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option formatter="checkbox" and then to show a checkbox when the user selects "edit row", edittype="checkbox".